# Why doesn't LLVM SIMD-vectorize this code?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'vec.ir'
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0"

define void @patch(i64) {
entry:
  %1 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4388240000 to float*)
  %2 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387644544 to float*)
  %3 = fadd float %1, %2
  %4 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387729024 to float*)
  %5 = fadd float %1, %4
  %6 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387730560 to float*)
  %7 = fadd float %1, %6
  %8 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387513984 to float*)
  %9 = fadd float %1, %8
  store float %3, float* inttoptr (i64 4371309760 to float*)
  call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117467608, i64 %0)
  store float %5, float* inttoptr (i64 4371851456 to float*)
  call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117465688, i64 %0)
  store float %7, float* inttoptr (i64 4371574976 to float*)
  call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117465528, i64 %0)
  store float %9, float* inttoptr (i64 4371576512 to float*)
  call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117466648, i64 %0)
  ret void
}

declare void @__tickValue(i64, i64)
```

When I run `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/opt -S -O3 vec.ir > vec-opt.ir`, I get:

```
; ModuleID = 'vec.ir'
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0"

define void @patch(i64) {
entry:
  %1 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4388240000 to float*), align 128
  %2 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387644544 to float*), align 128
  %3 = fadd float %1, %2
  %4 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387729024 to float*), align 128
  %5 = fadd float %1, %4
  %6 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387730560 to float*), align 128
  %7 = fadd float %1, %6
  %8 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4387513984 to float*), align 128
  %9 = fadd float %1, %8
  store float %3, float* inttoptr (i64 4371309760 to float*), align 64
  tail call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117467608, i64 %0)
  store float %5, float* inttoptr (i64 4371851456 to float*), align 64
  tail call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117465688, i64 %0)
  store float %7, float* inttoptr (i64 4371574976 to float*), align 64
  tail call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117465528, i64 %0)
  store float %9, float* inttoptr (i64 4371576512 to float*), align 64
  tail call void @__tickValue(i64 105553117466648, i64 %0)
  ret void
}

declare void @__tickValue(i64, i64)
```

Per http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#the-slp-vectorizer, I was hoping the `fadd` instructions would be combined.

**How can I determine more information about why the optimizer isn't vectorizing?**

Answer (score 2):

LLVM has internal cost models which will detect automatically if SIMD vectorization is beneficial. You can have diagnostics info by [adding some flags to your build line](http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#diagnostics)

You can also try to "force" vectorization by adding [some directives](http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#pragma-loop-hint-directives) in your code.

If you start from llvm IR and not from source code, you still have command [line switches for opt](http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#command-line-flags)